# Why I have an SQL Exception raised when I pass a DateTime parameter to my Stored proc?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

Here is the signature of the stored proc :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [set_info]

    @idFile_id int,
    @p_timestamp datetime
...
```

In my C# code here is the declaration of the parameter :

```
           command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_time_stamp", SqlDbType.DateTime));
           command.Parameters["@p_time_stamp"].Value = report.TimeStamp;
```

the SQL Exception raised message :  "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime."

The SqlValue of the command parameter is : "23jan12"

So I think it's because there is alpha characters in the SqlValue date.

**1°/ How to solve this problem ?**

**2°/ I don't know why passing same parameters type is not safe for some types and safe for some other types.**

EDIT :

report.TimeStamp is not a `String` but a `DateTime` type variable

EDIT 2 :

I finally found the error which was a human error :( the problem was not about this parameter which worked correctly... Sorry to have lose your time...

Comment: What data type is your report.timestamp property?

Comment: Your `report.TimeStamp` should be of type `DateTime` as well, not a string.

Comment: Parse string to date or try 23-Jan-12.

Comment: Also the stored procedure is expecting '@p_timestamp' and not '@p_time_stamp'

Comment: Post more of the SP - if the parameter is indeed a `DateTime`, there is some sort of conversion happening from a `VARCHAR` field to a `DateTime`. Are you comparing to a `VARCHAR` field somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter name in code does not match the Stored Procedure.  It's probably trying to convert a blank string or something like that to a DateTime as no value will be passed to the expected `@p_timestamp` variable; as you have specified `@p_time_stamp` in code.

The changes below reflect the parameter name expected in your Stored Procedure:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_timestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime));
command.Parameters["@p_timestamp"].Value = report.TimeStamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your report.TimeStamp is a string, why not simply create a DateTime object from it and pass that to the stored procedure instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = MyDateFormatParse(report.TimeStamp);
command.Parameters["@p_time_stamp"].Value =  dt;
```

Use DateTime parameter value instead of string.